# How to save PDF generated by chromehtml2pdf to local folder?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I'm using this tool to export PDF from web page. From the author's instruction

> Once installed, simple command line usage is:
>
> chromehtml2pdf --out=out.pdf https://wikipedia.org
>
> to generate a PDF of that web page.
>
> For local files use:
>
> chromehtml2pdf --out=out.pdf file:///path/to/file/file.htm

Could you please explain how to use the command `chromehtml2pdf --out=out.pdf file:///path/to/file/file.htm` to save the PDF of https://wikipedia.org to folder '`C:\Users\Dung Le\Downloads\Documents`?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my bad, I've just figured it out :)

`chromehtml2pdf --out="E:\Trial\test.pdf" hhttps://wikipedia.org`